# Rails: Can I use newrelic_logwatcher_agent on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, heroku, newrelic

I just added the gem and tried to install the newrelic_agent file, but I get some strange errors saying the key is nill.

```
[2014-09-26 06:47:41 UTC] INFO: Using Ruby SDK version: 1.3.1
[2014-09-26 06:47:41 UTC] INFO: Agent Logwatcher is at version 0.0.2
[2014-09-26 06:47:41 UTC] INFO: Agent Logwatcher is at version 0.0.2
[2014-09-26 06:47:41 UTC] DEBUG: Start collecting agent data for poll cycle
[2014-09-26 06:47:41 UTC] DEBUG: Finished collecting agent data for poll cycle
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@xxxxx/bundler/gems/newrelic_plugin-fffddc35e908/lib/newrelic_platform_binding/component.rb:14:in `key': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

am I not suppose to run this locally or it can't be done ?

Comment: Make sure `gem 'newrelic_rpm'` line is outside any groups in your Gemfile (e.g. development or test). After adding the gem, bundle install and commit your changes to Gemfile and Gemfile.lock.

Comment: it's at the bottom of my gemfile, inside no groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search and not finding any solutions or answers heres what I have as a ***temp solution***

I looked into Heroku addons and I found a quite good bunch for startups:

https://addons.heroku.com/keen

https://addons.heroku.com/flydata

https://addons.heroku.com/logentries

hopefully this will save someones else's time.

Update:
just realized https://addons.io/products have a good list as well.